# Editing CSS Media Queries in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, function, media-queries

This is the part of the functions.php file

```
function javascript_file(){ 
    //this is the second style sheet for media query in wordpress
    wp_enqueue_style( 'container-css',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/container.css',array(),null, 'only screen and  (max-width:650px)' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'container-css' );
}

//applying action on this function
add_action('init','javascript_file');
```

In this I am adding the code for the media query in WordPress,
the code is working well in the developer tool in the browser but 
when I put on the server the code starting messing up,
in other words does't work.

The size which I chose for is 4 inches and above screen.

Comment: we need some details... what is the actual problem ? css not loading ...?

Comment: css not loading means

Comment: there is two file which i made to load css in different device 1>style.css for desktop 2>container.css for mobile .when m uploading the theme on server the code of style.css working well but container.css is going to be fail .in other words not loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media queries in wordpress dashboard in Appearance -> Editor. Simple copy and paste your media quesries in that.

Comment: actually i  make to css file 1st files 1>style.css 2>container.css

Comment: 1>style.css have a rregular query 2>container.css has media query css written ,so i have to load container.css when user wants to open the theme in mobile

Comment: its not necessary to create to different css files. you can write media queries in style.css too.